# Knokout.js and mapping with binding onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I think this question may be asked several time but I cant find any good solution

i have this html part and html inside a dialog

```
<a href="#" title="3" class="button color" id="learnmore">Learn More</a>
     <div id="dialogID" class="learnmore-dialog" title="More Information" style="display:none;">
    <h4 data-bind="text: ProgramName"></h4>
      <strong>Program Objectives</strong>:
        <span data-bind="text: ProgramObjective"></span>
       <strong>Program Speaker</strong>:
       <br><span data-bind="text: Speacker"></span>
       <br>
       <br><strong>Program Locations</strong>:
        <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: displocation">
        <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Address"></span>
        <br><span data-bind="text: LocationName"></span>
        <br><span data-bind="text: City"></span>, <span data-bind="text: State"></span> <span data-bind="text: Zip"></span>
        </td>
         <td>
        <span data-bind="text: ProgramLocationStartDateString"></span>-----<span data-bind="text: ProgramLocationEndDateString"></span>
         </td>
          </tr>
         </tbody></table>
          </div>
```

and i have a script

```
 <script>
     $("#learnmore").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var winW = $('#main .container').width();
        if (winW > 767)
         winW = winW - 200;
         var prid = $(this).attr("title")
       $.getJSON('http://getjson', function (result) {
          var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
          ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
          })
         $("#dialogID").dialog({
       width: winW,
          modal: true
       });
     });
        </script>
```

the problem is the i am getting this error

You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

obviously because I apply binding every time the button is clicked so i can get a new json is there anyway to solve this issue or do it differently 
Thanks

Comment: Do you apply bindings before call getjson ? and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using jQuery in this way goes against the Knockout mentality, but using it properly solves your problem.

```
<a data-bind="click: showDialog" href="#" title="3" class="button color" id="learnmore">Learn More</a>
```

This if binding causes Knockout to not render the children elements unless you have the JSON data loaded, and the `with` binding makes everything in the context of the JSON.

```
<div data-bind="if: dialgoStuff().ProgramObjective, with: dialogStuff()" id="dialogID" class="learnmore-dialog" title="More Information" style="display:none;"></div>
```

You should then create a ViewModel with an observable for the data.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.dialogStuff = ko.observable({});
```

And put your click handler in here.  Since you're not changing values of the JSON data, except for replacing it all-together, you don't need the mapping plugin.

```
    self.showDialog = function (data, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var winW = $('#main .container').width();
        if (winW > 767) winW = winW - 200;
        var prid = $(this).attr("title")
        $.getJSON('http://getjson', function (result) {
            self.dialogStuff(result);
        })
        $("#dialogID").dialog({
            width: winW,
            modal: true
        });
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```